# How does parent component re-render a redux state which updated by its child modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am using a modal child component from my parent component. OnSubmit of the modal, it updates the redux state which has rendered in my parent component. (behind the modal).

My child component (modal) successfully updates the redux store.
When I close the modal, parent has the old rendered content.

I want to update my parent component's rendered content by updated redux state when closing the modal.
what is the way to do above scenario in react-redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put your code in codesandbox?

From your description, it seems like that your parent component rendered for the first time with the initial correct value but failed to re-render the new value after state in redux store updates.

This often happens when the value you want it to update has no direct link to the redux store.

If you do not understand what I just said, here is an example:

In parent component, you may have the following code:

```
        class Parent extends Component{
             state={name:this.props.name}
             render(){
               <input value={this.state.name} onChange= 
                  {this.onChange.bind(this)} />
                 }
           }
```

In this example, you initialize your state for the first render, but after the first render, the parent component has no relationship with redux store, it becomes an uncontrolled component.

Ertan said using `componentWillReceiveProps` . A lot of people do that. They initialize local state from external props and then use `componentWillReceiveProps` to update local state.

But this is not recommended and this lifecycle method is now depreciated because it can lead to potential bugs. see here for more info: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

**So the solution to your problem is actually very simple:**

Do not initialize the value in local state. Give the value a direct link to redux store. For example:

```
    class Parent extends Component {
        state={
           name:null //do not give it a value from external props
           }
       render(){
         <input value={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
         }
     }
```

Hope it helps.
Thanks.

Comment: You save my week. Thank you. Accessing redux store directly solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you are saving the redux data in the state, then just use `componentWillRecieveProps(newProps)` method and then update the state. Otherwise you can still use `componentWillRecieveProps` to check if the store is updating successfully.

Comment: thank you for answering. the problem is that the store has already updated. but parent does not re-render the updated state.